# Ajax - hide link after being clicked

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var url = document.URL;
      var strg = url.toString();
function StartAjax(ResultsId){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "mark.php",
      cache: false,
    data: (strg),
      success: function(html){
        $("#"+ResultsId).append(html);
        **$("#").hide();**
      }

    });

}
</script>

<br><a href="#" name="link"  onclick="StartAjax('ResultsId');">Proceed</a>
<div id="ResultsId"></div>
```

The Ajax does what it's supposed to do, but how do i hide the link after it's been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to do a $(this).hide(); or you can give the anchor tag a class so

```
<br><a href="#" name="link" class="thisBtn" onclick="StartAjax('ResultsId');">Proceed</a>
```

and then

```
success: function(html){
    $("#"+ResultsId).append(html);
    $(".thisBtn').hide();
  }
```

Comment: `$(this).hide()` would fail because the AJAX callback sets a new `this` context.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" name="link" class="clickme" onclick="StartAjax('ResultsId');">Proceed</a>

    $('.clickme').click(function(event){

        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "mark.php",
          cache: false,
        data: (strg),
          success: function(html){
            $("#"+ResultsId).append(html);

            $(_this).hide();

          }

        });

});
```

So what you do here is register click event on you  and once it runs you save reference to current element. Since it's still running in the same scope you can then access it in *success* and you can hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially asking "how do I select elements with jQuery". In your HTML's current state, the link would probably be targeted like so:

```
$('a[name=link]').hide();
```

However, since the code is running in an event callback invoked BY the link, we can use a relative reference to it. @Jure C.'s answer shows one means of this. Another would be:

```
success: (function(link) { return function(html) {
    $('#'+ResultsId).append(html);
    link.hide();
}; })($(this))
```